# How to add a parameter to a graphql query with edges and nodes

Tags: graphql, graphiql

To return all the data, I can use

```
    {
      allEmployees {
        edges {
          node {
            id
            name
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

I have the variable
`{"name": "Roy"}`

How do I select all the employees named Roy?

Answer (score 1):

This depends on what your GraphQL schema looks like. Capabilities like filtering aren't part of GraphQL, they're something that you can build into your GraphQL schema. I would look into what arguments the `allEmployees` field accepts.